# Plotly: treemap element with "href" not working

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have simple table whin `href` link inside the text. But clicking on it doesn't open the page.
is there any easy way to do that?

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

link_ref = '<a xlink:href="http://google.com" style="cursor: pointer" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{}</a>'
df['country'] = df['country'].apply(lambda item: link_ref.format(item, "{}"))

fig = px.treemap(df, path=[ 'continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You want to have a action on click for every country, isn't?

Comment: yes. I actually want open a link from clicking on the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get rid of `xlink:` The following should work

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

link_ref = '<a href="http://google.com" style="cursor: pointer" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{}</a>'
df['country'] = df['country'].apply(lambda item: link_ref.format(item, "{}"))

fig = px.treemap(df,
                 path=[ 'continent', 'country'],
                 values='pop',
                 color='lifeExp',
                 hover_data=['iso_alpha'])

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks it works, one side question, how to give relatvie path to local html file? e.g
`link_ref = '<a href="pages/page1.html" style="cursor: pointer" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{}</a>'`. Unfortunatelly this doesn't work.

Comment: Could you also look into following. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62967338/plotly-treemap-element-with-href-not-working-with-local-relative-html-paths