# plotly treemap element with “href” not working with local relative html paths

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have simple table with href inside the text. The href points to relative path of local html file.
But clicking on it doesn't open the page. is there any way to do that/ good workaround?

The folder structure is following. As the root will be changed, so the relative path is needed.

```
--root
--root/index.html
--root/files/file1.html
--root/files/file2.html



import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

link_ref = '<a href="files/file1.html">{}</a>'
df['country'] = df['country'].apply(lambda item: link_ref.format(item))
fig = px.treemap(df, path=[ 'continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'])
fig.write_html("index.html")
```

Note: The link starting with `http` works. [Plotly: treemap element with "href" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955631/plotly-treemap-element-with-href-not-working/62961999#62961999)

```
link_ref = '<a href="http://google.com">{}</a>'
```

[image]

**Update:**

The following link partially works.

```
link_ref = '<a href="http:///files/file1.html">{}</a>'
```

Comment: you are working in jupyter notebook?

Comment: no, I am not using Jupter nootbook and dash.

Comment: Try giving absolute path of the html file in the `href` attribute

Comment: no. Absoule path also doesn't seems to work for me.

Comment: one thing that seems odd to me is you have `link_ref.format(item)` but `link_ref` doesn't have any format specifier so that doesn't do anything, also your `<a>` tag doesn't have any content in it, is it possible you want `<a ...>{}</a>` so text gets inserted into your tag?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, yup you right. I forgot to add `{}` in example above. I will update now. Thanks

Comment: `link_ref='<a href="http://localhost/files/file1.html">{}</a>`Does this work?

Comment: When I open `index.html` in `chrome`, it tries to open `localhost/files/file1.html`

Comment: What browser are you using? http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File links are an issue for security reasons. I tested this code with IE 11 and it worked fine, no issues. For Firefox, Chrome, and Edge it does not work.

You may be able to disable this security check in your browser or use an extension. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

link_ref = '<a href="./text.html">{}</a>'
df['country'] = df['country'].apply(lambda item: link_ref.format(item))
fig = px.treemap(df, path=[ 'continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'])
fig.write_html("index.html")
```