# Is there a way to add a hyperlink to an image in plotly?

Tags: python, hyperlink, plotly

I am trying to take an image stored on a web server and be able to add a hyper-link to it taking you back to the home page. Here is an example from plotly documentation on how to add an image to a graph:

```
fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(
        source="https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png",
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
        x=0,
        y=3,
        sizex=2,
        sizey=2,
        sizing="stretch",
        opacity=0.5,
        layer="below")
```

)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: treemap element with "href" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955631/plotly-treemap-element-with-href-not-working)

Comment: @rpanai No, it does not deal with hyperlinking an entire image.